# How to extract all id's from a JSON response using JSON JMESPasth Extractor in Jmeter?

Tags: json, while-loop, jmeter, automated-tests, jmespath

I created a get request to get all the entries which is 997 entries and used JSON JMESPath Extractor to store the entries ids in a list. The JMESPath expression I used is  `entries[*].id`  and I used ForEach Controller to loop through the list and use each value of the list in next http request. The problem is that I want to get the ids of all 997 entries in the list, not just 10 values which is given at once by JMESPath extractor. I tried to take the length of entries as *len* and used While Controller to loop 100 times so that I can execute the next http request about 1000 times with condition `((${len}+3)/10)`. But, no matter how many times the loop executes, the values in the list obtained from JMESPath Extractor remains the same.
The Json response I get is similar as shown below.

```
{
  "total": 997,
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": 123389,
      "parent-customer": [
        {
          "id": 123775,
          "value": "Donal Thornber"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I have only kept one entry for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get all the IDs in a single shot -  the easiest would be going for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), it provides `..` [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) so the expression like `$..id` will match **all** the `id` attributes values no matter where they are:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)